# Stripping text file with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to take all the punctuation out of a text file. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
fname = open("text.txt","r")

stripped = ""
for line in fname:
    for c in line:
        if c in '!,.?-':
            c = ""
        stripped = stripped + c
print(stripped)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
with open("text.txt","r") as r:
    text = r.read()


with open("text.txt","w") as w:
    w.write(re.sub(r'[!,.?-]', '', text))
```

What about this?

Or there is a way without regex:

```
with open("text.txt","r") as r:
    text = r.read()

with open("text.txt","w") as w:
    for i in '!,.?-':
        text = text.replace(i, '')

    w.write(text)
```

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 No, ``with open("text.txt","r") as r:`` will save the text of `text.txt` to memory(into `r`). So open it to write will not clear the text of `r`.

Comment: The line with `with...` doesn't save the contents of the file at all. It just opens the file and creates a handle. If you tested this and it works, that's great, but this sort of thing is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Okay, I've just edit my answer and do something like `text = r.read()` :P

Answer (score 0):

You could try a regular expression, substituting any punctuation character with the empty string:

```
import re
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(re.sub(r'[.!,?-]', '', line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually *much* faster than regular expressions or individual string manipulations or construction is using `str.translate`:

```
# Python 2 solution
with open("text.txt","r") as fname:
    stripped = fname.read().translate(None, '!,.?-')
```

Note, that's not all punctuation. Best way to get all ASCII punctuation is to `import string` and use `string.punctuation`.

In Python 3, you can do either:

```
# Read as text and translate with str.translate
delete_punc_table = str.maketrans('', '', '!,.?-') # If you're using the table more than once, always define once, use many times
with open("text.txt","r") as fname:
    stripped = fname.read().translate(delete_punc_table)

# Read as bytes to use Py2-like ultra-efficient translate then decode
with open("text.txt", "rb") as fname:
    stripped = fname.read().translate(None, b'!,.?-').decode('ascii')  # Or some other ASCII superset encoding
    # If you use string.punctuation for the bytes approach
    # you'd need to encode it, e.g. translate(None, string.punctuation.encode('ascii'))
```

Before Python 3.4, the "read bytes, translate, then decode" approach was *absurdly* better, in 3.4+ it's probably still slightly faster, but not enough to make a huge difference.

Timings for various methods on my computer (using Python 3.5 x64 for Windows):

```
# Make random ~100KB input
data = ''.join(random.choice(string.printable) for i in range(100000))

# Using re.sub (with a compiled regex to minimize overhead)
>>> min(timeit.repeat('trans.sub("", data)', 'from __main__ import re, string, data; trans = re.compile(r"[" + re.escape(string.punctuation) + r"]")', number=1000))
17.47419076158849

# Using iterative str.replace
>>> min(timeit.repeat('d2 = data\nfor l in punc: d2 = d2.replace(l, "")', 'from __main__ import string, data; punc = string.punctuation', number=1000))
13.51673370949311

# Using str.translate
>>> min(timeit.repeat('data.translate(trans)', 'from __main__ import string, data; trans = str.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation)', number=1000))
1.5299288690396224

# Using bytes.translate then decoding as ASCII (without the decode, this is close to how Py2 would behave)
>>> bdata = data.encode("ascii")
>>> min(timeit.repeat('bdata.translate(None, trans).decode("ascii")', 'from __main__ import string, bdata; trans = string.punctuation.encode("ascii")', number=1000))
1.294337291624089
```

The times are the best time to run 1000 conversion loops in 3 test runs (taking the minimum is considered the best way to avoid timing jitter affecting your results), in seconds, for my input of 100,000 random printable things `re.sub` (even precompiled) isn't even close. Either `translate` method is fine (`bytes.translate` may be faster, but it's also more complicated code). `str.replace` is more competitive if the set of things to replace is smaller (using only `'!,.?-'` instead of all punctuation drops it to ~3 secconds), but it's slower for any reasonable number of characters to strip, and doesn't scale like the `translate`s do.

Comment: If memory is a concern and you expect stripping to cut down on input size dramatically, you can read lines or blocks from the file and translate each one individually, but translating the whole input at once is going to be fastest if the file can fit in main memory.